# Sending ASCII and protocol commands to server

Tags: java, sockets

I managed to setup a client and server connection using Java socket.  After checking the connection had been establish, I tried sending Protocol commands that are provided by the SDK from the server and I'm using a JButton to execute the commands.

Examples of the commands are play, stop and ping the server.

The code below shows how I setup the connection and send the protocol commands

```
public void socket1()
{
    Socket MyClient;
    try {
        MyClient = new Socket("192.168.10.61",9993);
        os = new DataOutputStream(MyClient.getOutputStream());
        is = new DataInputStream(MyClient.getInputStream());
        lblerror.setText("Connected");
        MyClient.getOutputStream().write("play".getBytes("US-ASCII"));
    } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
         lblerror.setText("Don't know about host: hostname");

    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        lblerror.setText("Couldn't get I/O for the connection to: hostname");

    }


}
```

After pressing the button on the GUI, The server did not response to the command 'play' and there is no error.

Comment: `MyClient.getOutputStream().write` -> `os.write`

Comment: Is the server definitely expecting the format used by `DataOutputStream`? If it's not written in Java, it may well not be. Are you sure you're not meant to put an end-of-line marker after each command?

Answer (score 0):

As Scarry Wombat wrote, use `os.write()`
But instead of `.write()` use `.writeBytes()`,
because you want to send a byte array(?). Alternatively you could send a String with UTF-encoding by using `.writeUTF()`

Comment: i tried both os.writeBytes() and os.writeUTF(), both return as error and got me to correct back to os.write()

Comment: Try byte[] buffer = yourstringhere.getBytes() and then send the bytearray with .writeBytes

Comment: Can you please post the error output when using .writeBytes